# How would you draw a node in the slider track in swiftUI/Swift?

Tags: swift, swiftui, uislider

How would you draw a node/bubble in the slider track in swiftUI/Swift? Needed 10 nodes for 10 values.
I took the help of the png (if that helps) and it moves perfectly fine (jumps from one node to another), however, I also need the track background colour along with these nodes. Not sure how to do it.

[Hyperlinking](https://www.google.com/search?q=custom%20slider%20nodes%20swift&tbm=isch&hl=en-IN&chips=q:seekbar%20custom%20slider%20nodes%20swift,online_chips:seekbar,online_chips:ios&hl=en-GB&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi3kunzu7PsAhUOBrcAHRIGAeQQ4lYoCHoECAEQHg&biw=1905&bih=841#imgrc=v9B83CuLOZrQHM) the demo for what I've been looking for

This is what I did.

```
let trackingImage = UIImage(named:"bubbles")!

func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UISlider {
let slider = UISlider(frame: .zero)
slider.thumbTintColor = thumbColor
slider.minimumTrackTintColor = minTrackColor
slider.maximumTrackTintColor = maxTrackColor
slider.value = Float(value)
slider.minimumValue = 0
slider.maximumValue = 9    
slider.setMinimumTrackImage(trackingImage, for:.normal)
slider.setMaximumTrackImage(trackingImage, for:.normal)
slider.minimumTrackTintColor = .systemBlue

slider.addTarget(
  context.coordinator,
  action: #selector(Coordinator.valueChanged(_:)),
  for: .valueChanged
)

return slider
```

}

Answer (score 1):

This will sound very naive, but to answer my own question, I've simply added the image of that type (bar and circle/node together) by setting the image to **setMinimumTrackImage** and **setMaximumTrackImage** image.

```
let trackingImage = UIImage(named:"slider_unselected")!
let trackedImage = UIImage(named:"selectedTracl82")!  
@Binding var value: Int

func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UISlider {

let slider = UISlider(frame: .zero)
slider.thumbTintColor = thumbColor
slider.minimumTrackTintColor = minTrackColor
slider.value = Float(value)
slider.minimumValue = 0
slider.maximumValue = 9    
slider.setMinimumTrackImage(trackedImage, for:.normal)
slider.setMaximumTrackImage(trackingImage, for:.normal)
```

Posted in case somebody might get into same issue.